# Why don't we see rainbows from mirrors?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, reflection, refraction

[image: ..]

Should this not be the case whenever light strikes a thick mirror on the whole (obliquely)??
Someone please clarify.

Comment: We would, if we had thick enough mirrors and weren't distracted by coloration of the glass.

Comment: Did you try to do the math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These rainbows exist and our eyes **do** see them - they are just extremely thin, plus our brain filters out this information, but the edges of bright objects on dark background in the mirror do have a thin rainbow along them. Our eye is using this rainbow to infer the image comes from a mirror.

I once saw an exhibit at a modern art museum - a seemingly black-and-white painting. When looking at it, it felt like you were looking at a mirror, despite the image not depicting anything in the room. A closer look revealed that the artist added thin rainbow-colored edges to all objects on the drawing, which tricked the brain into thinking you were looking at a mirror.